# How to configure PHPStorm for UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, phpstorm

My settings are UTF8 for IDE-Encoding and project encoding but when I evaluate an expression, I get the following result :

[image]

Any Ideas ?

Comment: Can you give me that actual expression text? Seems to be OK here with this one: http://postimg.org/image/w2txdokrv/ . Maybe it should be done on PHP level instead?